# Android Intent BroadcastReceiver Example

Tags: c#, android, .net-core, .net-maui, zebra-scanners

I am using a Zebra Android Scan-Gun and need to capture the **hard-keyboard** (not soft) keystrokes for P1, P2, F1, F2, etc... keys.  Since Maui doesn't have events for `KeyUp`/`KeyDown`/`KeyPressed` there is nothing to inform me of a special keys being pressed.  Not to mention I also have to put an Entry field on screens where there are only buttons because you can't catch a `TextChanged` event without an Entry.

My current solution involves `Zebra StageNow` to remap the P1 key to the "+" key and then strip it out of the Entry/TextBox (which is not a very elegant solution)

What I'm trying now is using the Windows app `Zebra StageNow` in Admin mode to remap the F11 key to send an Intent, OnKeyUp, Broadcast as seen in this screenshot.

[image: Zebra StageNow Screenshot]

Then I generate the bar-codes to program the scan-gun.

In the Android Scan-gun I then run StageNow and scan the bar-codes which programs the F11 key.

Then within my android app I added a class in the `Platforms\Android` folder called `SpecialKeypress.cs`

```
namespace myapp.Platforms.Android
{

    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.mycompany.myapp.F11" })]

    public class SpecialKeypress : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            var value = intent.GetStringExtra("Key"); // <-- I set a breakpoint here
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added the following to my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
    
    <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.F11" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.F11" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    
  </application>
```

I debug the app on the device and press F11 but alas my breakpoint is not hit in the `OnReceive` function.

I expect I'm missing something fundamental but I tried to keep it as simple as possible for this example.  Also, there are no good examples of how to do this with Maui on the internet (yet).

Comment: May I know if your breakpoint directly skips the OnReceive function ？

Comment: Correct.  The breakpoint is not hit.

Comment: Ok. You may refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to register a receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml, and put some intent filters that define what type of messages this receiver will get.
For example:

```
<receiver android:name=".SpecialKeypress">
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```